# MemoryStream Stream does not support reading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, smtpclient

Got a MemoryStream which is used as an attachment in email. The SmtpClient.SendMessageCallback results in an exception "Stream does not support reading". What might be wrong? Thanks for any help!
Simplified, code looks like:

```
public Stream GetMemoryStream()
{
  ...
  var ms = new MemoryStream(fileBytes)
  {
    Position = 0
  };

  return ms;
} 

public void MailWithAttachment()
{
  using (Stream ms = GetMemoryStream())
  {
    ms.Position = 0;
    await MailAttachment(ms, "myPicture.jpg");
  }
}

public Task MailAttachment(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
  ...
  System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, ct);
  attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
  mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
  ...
  await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

Comment: Post the *actual* code and exception, not simplified code.  The code you posted contains no data. There's nothing to read

Comment: `await` in `void` method?

Comment: You disposed the MemoryStream before whatever was trying to read it, read it. Note that `MailAttachment` is `async void`, which means there's no way for the caller to know when the mailing has finished. Also note that `MailWithAttachment` does **not** `await` the call to `MailAttachment`, and goes on to dispose `ms` straight away. So `ms` gets disposed long before `SendMailAsync` finishes. This is one of the reasons we tell newbies not to use `async void`. Make your `MailAttachment` method `async Task`, and `await` it from `MailWithAttachment`

Comment: The stream length is 2068488.

Comment: @canton7 for reference, in an edit: `MailAttachment` *is* now awaited; however, `MailAttachment` is also clearly pseudo-code, as it too has `await` without `async`; to OP: please post **real code** - the details matter **a lot**, and you're hiding them from us

Comment: @Gerard `2068488` is the capacity, not the stream length *in the code you posted*. This question will be closed without the actual code. What you posted won't even compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't "async all the way" and the compiler will have given you a warning/error about using `await` in a method that isn't `async`.

You need to make `MailWithAttachment` and `MailAttachment` `async` and then use `await` correctly. For example:

```
public async Task MailWithAttachment()
{
  using (Stream ms = GetMemoryStream())
  {
    ms.Position = 0;
    await MailAttachment(ms, "myPicture.jpg");
  }
}

public async Task MailAttachment(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
  ...
  System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(stream, ct);
  attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
  mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
  ...
  await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
}
```

Comment: note that in an edit OP has made `MailAttachment` be awaited (I commented more on this on the question)

Comment: Using `await` in a non-`async` method is an error, not a warning. Is your first para a confusion with calling an awaitable method and not using await being the one that generates the warning ("Because this call is not awaited..")?